# Getting Device Type and Android SDK from Crash Reports

Tags: android

The marketplace crash reports do not provide enough information about what version of android is being used for me to replicate the errors.  How can I request that more information be provided on crash reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It would be best if you used a third party solution like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/). It can provide you with very detailed reports.

Comment: JAGHAV  question.  What is ACRA and can it be used with a commerically deployed app. How does this work?

Comment: Integration instructions are given at http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup. And yes, you can use it in a commercially deployed app.

Comment: Are there additional permissions required?

Comment: Only INTERNET. If you have READ_LOGS, you'll get an even more detailed report, but it's optional.